# Converting regular time interval to non uniform

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, dataset

I have a time series data set with multiple features. This data set is collected over 8 hours of time at regular intervals of 5 mins. How can i resample and select the data in exponential scale? I mean i would like to take the data at 5th min, 15th min, 1st hour etc...

Comment: What do you mean? How is the sequence 5, 15, 60 exponential?

Comment: My example may be wrong. But what I meant was time interval between two time slot is non uniform and gap increases exponential

Comment: So generate an exponential sequence of random numbers and draw the value of your time series at those values?

Comment: Yes.. Correct. Based on my minimum and maximum time stamp I want to get the exponential intervals

Comment: There are many ways to do that, can you post some sample data that we can work with?